# Маппинг json в DTO с помощью Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Друзья, добрый день!
Есть такая dto'шка:

```
public class HarDto {

    private Long id;
    private String version;
    private String browserName;
    private String browserVersion;
    private JsonNode content;
}
```

И json такой структуры:

```
{
    "log": {
        "version": "1.2",
        "creator": {
            "name": "Firefox",
            "version": "70.0.1"
        },
        "browser": {
            "name": "Firefox",
            "version": "70.0.1"
        },
        "pages": [
            {
                "startedDateTime": "2019-12-02T16:59:06.443+03:00",
                "id": "page_1",
                "pageTimings": {
                    "onContentLoad": 3936,
                    "onLoad": 7985
                }
            }
        ],
        "entries": [
            {...
```

Мне нужно как можно меньшими усилиями смпаить json в dto. От рутового элемента я избавился таким образом:

```
objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
```

+

```
@JsonRootName("log")
public class HarDto {}
```

Но остается проблема с browserVersion и browserName.
Могу ли я как-то получить их из json'а, не используя отдельный класс или не переделывая две строки(browser version and name) в map?
Что-то типа

```
@JsonProperty("browser.name")
private String browserName;
```

Заранее огромное спасибо за помощь.

**UPDATE**

@Andrew Bystrov подсказал, как оказалось, самый простой и действенный вариант, решил вопрос таким образом: сделал data class, который содержал в себе полную структуру json, мапил в него, а потом на уровне сервиса написал простенький конвертер `dtoToEntity`

Comment: Можно представить как мапу. `HashMap<String, String> browser = new HashMap();`. Пометьте ее в классе аннотацией `@JsonProperty("browser")`

Comment: Да, я знаю про такой вариант, однако не хочу его использовать(придется много чего переписывать), также знаю про такой вариант:
private void initBrowser(Map<String, String> map) {
this.browserName = map.get("name");
...
}
Он мне не подходит, так как ломается десериализация.

Поэтому решил уточнить, возможны ли варианты, не ломающие существующий код

Comment: создайте полный DTO на основе вашей json и уже на основе полной DTO создавайте HarDto

Comment: @СтёпаФомичёв, я не сталкивался с другими вариантами на практике, возможно они и есть, но больше будут похожи на велосипед.